# Robot framework with java: where to put browser driver path?

Tags: selenium, java, robotframework, eclipse

I'm trying to set up a maven+robot+selenium3+testNG project using Eclipse and java.

So far, I've created a maven project and added the dependencies and plugins to its pom.xml so I don't have to manually download anything. I added the following dependencies: `selenium-java`, `selenium-server` (not sure if I need it), `testng`, `robotframework`, `robotframework-maven-plugin`, `robotframework-selenium2library-java`, and also the `robotframework-maven-plugin`.

I also added a tests.robot file under src/test/robotframework/acceptance with this test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library


*** Test Cases ***
Visit google
  Open Browser  https://www.google.com  chrome
  Close Browser
```

However, I'm not sure how to tell robot where my chromedriver is. Currently, when I run as maven-install, I get `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;`

I read somewhere that I should create my own keyword and then use `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path\\chromedriver.exe");`
but I don't really know how to create my own keywords in java, and how to connect them with robot.

Comment: I used Set Environment Variable webdriver.gecko.driver ${CURDIR}${/}drivers${/}geckodriver.exe but the program displays this error WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found out how to do it:

I created a .java file within src/main/java/mycompany and added a method that sets up the property:

```
package mycompany;

public class Setup {
    public void browserSetup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
    }
}
```

Then, in my test, I imported this as a library:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  mycompany.Setup
```

And then invoked the method as a new keyword: `Browser Setup`.

That was it. I ran it and it worked.

EDIT: Just in case anyone is wondering how to reference chromedriver.exe as a relative path within the project, I placed the exe file in my **{root_project_directory}\src\test\resources** directory, then used it as `src\\test\\resources\\chromedriver.exe` (notice the `\` escaping needed).

Comment: I am puzzled that how does it even work! 1. Your function name was 'browserSetup' in Java. How did it become the Robot Framework keyword 'Browser Setup'? I observed that Robot Framework is processes camel case java functions and creates them as space separated keywords. How is it possible? 2. I am happy that this is working. Now, I would like to enhance this java function to pass the driver from .robot files. How can I do that. Example: I would like to pass the webdriver from .robot file along with table locator and process the table to validate the rows. How can I do it?

Comment: Floella, I'm commenting to highlight you on the SE bar because I Santosh's comment was accidentally posted as an answer and I wanted to make sure the highlight went through. =)

Answer (score 1):

'Create Webdriver' keyword allows passing argument to `WebDriver's __init__`, this means that it can pass argument to the constructor of WebDriver class. And WebDriver class constructor has an argument as `'executable_path'` which is the path of the webdriver exe file.

We can use keyword arguments i.e `kwargs={}` to pass arguments to the the WebDriver Constructor. We have to create keyword dictionary and pass it in as argument `kwargs`.

This is the detail of keyword Create WebDriver:

Create `Webdriver driver_name, alias=None, kwargs={}, **init_kwargs`

Code to launch webdriver from custom path and launch URL:

```
*** Variables ***
${Driver_Path}=     C:${/}webdriver${/}chromedriver.exe
${url}=     google.com

*** Keywords ***
${dict}     Create Dictonary    executable_path=${Driver_Path}
Create Webdriver    driver_name=Chrome  kwargs=${dict}
Maximize Browser Window
Go To   ${url}
```

Answer (score 1):

set up a environment variable like this:

```
Set Environment Variable    webdriver.chrome.driver   C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe
```